# Javascript - add signature in specific places on a previously generated PDF

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing, pdf, signature

I would like to add signatures to specific areas of a pdf that I previously generated.

I would need to parse the PDF, find the spots where I need a signature and add the picture of a signature

Our PDFs have variable lengths (depending on clients).

When building the pdf the first time, is there a way to leave an indicator such as an id/class letting me know where to place the signature later.
A specific xml tag might work.

I’m not sure how feasible it is.
Pretty hard to look for answers

We’re using JS, haven’t decided yet on a specific Pdf library. Seeing our case, we need one that allows us to parse an existing pdf.

Thank you!

Comment: The LEADTOOLS library has the [AnnImageObject](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/dh/javascript/ac/annimageobject.html) annotation which can be placed then "burned" to the PDF using the picture. Alternatively, the library also has the ```DocumentSignature``` and ```DocumentSignatureFormField``` objects for generating and placing signatures. See the demo [here](https://demo.leadtools.com/JavaScript/Apps/Documentviewer/index.html?mode=DocumentSignature). The code for this is available in the free evaluation [here](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads) (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor)